# Behat select2 ajax closes the search box

Tags: ajax, symfony, behat, jquery-select2

I want to test with Behat a select2 dropbox that makes an ajax call in order to get the results.
The problem is that immediately after I populate the search box of select2 the dropdown closes immediately so the search is not happening.

If the select is already populated (a normal dropdown with predefined values) everything is ok because all the data is there and it takes it right away.

I'm using `Behat Page object` for my project so here is my method:

> select2FieldPopulate

```
public function select2FieldPopulate($field, $value)
{
    $select2Field = $this->find('css', '.'.$field);

    //check if select2Field exists
    if (!$select2Field) {
        throw new \Exception(sprintf("Field %s was not found", $field));
    }

    $select2Field->click();

    $select2Input = $this->find('css', '.select2-drop.select2-drop-active .select2-search input.select2-input');

    if (!$select2Input) {
        throw new \Exception(sprintf("Field %s was not found", "select2-input"));
    }

    $select2Input->setValue($value);
}
```

> js

```
function buildSelect2Element(selector, placeholder, url) {
    var element = $(selector).select2({
        placeholder: placeholder,
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        ajax: {
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (term) {
                return {
                    q: term
                }
            },
            results: function (data) {

                //workarround to fix select2
                var results = [];
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    results.push({
                        id: item.id,
                        text: item.name
                    });
                });
                return {
                    results
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return element;
}
```

On `$select2Input->setValue()` the search box gets populated with the value but the search does not happen because the dropdown closes right away.

So the question is: Is there a way to force the box to stay open until the results are displayed (the ajax call is finished)?

Comment: The select should behave as manual and you might need to simulate typing(keyboard press) instead of setting the value.Also you might want to have a single method to find the element and return the object if found or throw exception instead of handling this in the method you need for each element/action.

Comment: ok, i managed to make the search with `select2('search', 'key')` but now i am stucked on how to click on the highlighted value ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work under select2 v4.x.

I added to the js the option to select on close like this:

> js

```
function buildSelect2Element(selector, placeholder, url) {
    var element = $(selector).select2({
        theme: "classic",
        placeholder: placeholder,
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        selectOnClose: true, //HERE
```

Then in my tests i used the evaluateScript method:

> select2FieldPopulate method

```
$this->getDriver()->evaluateScript("$('#your_select2_element').select2('open')");
$this->getDriver()->evaluateScript("$('.select2-search__field').val('". $value ."').keyup();");
$this->getDriver()->evaluateScript("$('#your_select2_element').select2('close')");
```